# Speeding up nested loops in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, nested

I have a large datframe (about 3 million rows) which contain an ID, a year and three dates each: `lookupdate`, `date1` and `date2`. The `data.frame` is sorted by `ID` and `date1`. I want to search through the whole data set and find the records `i` which:

- are of `financial_year == 2013` and
- contain the same `ID` as any other line `j` such that `date1[j] < lookupdate[i] < date2[j]`

I have implemented this logic below, but it is ridiculously slow. Do you have any idea how to speed up this code?

```
calc_hits_bruteforce <- function(d){
  N <- nrow(d)
  hits <- rep(FALSE, N)
  for (i in 2:N) {
    if(d[i,"financial_year"]!=2013) next
    for (j in i:1) {
      if (d[i,"ID"]!=d[j,"ID"]) {
        break
      }
      else {
        if (d[j,"date1"] < d[i,"lookupdate"] & d[j, "date2"] > d[i, "lookupdate"]) {
          hits[i] <- TRUE
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  hits
}
```

I don't know how many records there are for each `ID`, but I know the `lookupdate` for each record lies before `date1` and `date2`, i.e. `lookupdate[i] < date1[i] < date2[i]` for all `i`.

Here's an example of the dataframe and the output:

```
> d.ex
    ID     lookupdate      date1      date2 financial_year
1 C143896B 2011-02-24 2011-11-09 2011-11-21           2011
2 C143896G 2010-11-23 2011-10-29 2011-11-21           2011
3 C143896G 2011-11-11 2012-10-12 2012-11-05           2012
4 C143896G 2012-06-17 2013-01-30 2013-02-11           2013
5 C143896G 2012-10-31 2013-09-15 2013-09-29           2013
> calc_hits_bruteforce(d.ex)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The last row is TRUE since 2012-10-12 < 2012-10-31 < 2012-11-05.

Comment: Nested loops are very hard to read. The best practice would be if you will add a **minimal reproducible** example with a **desired output**

Comment: Thanks, added an example.

Comment: Should financial_year == 2013 or financial_year!=2013 ?

Comment: financial_year should equal 2013, that's why in the above code I skip to the next `i` if it's not 2013.

Comment: you can use the function dput to create table as the one above. It's easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you pose the question, it sounds like you're interested in a logical vector of length equal to the number of rows in `d`, so *pre-allocate* that

```
hits = logical(nrow(d))  ## initialized to 'FALSE'
```

You're interested in the subset of rows from a particular financial year, so *vectorize* the selection

```
i_idx <- which(d$financial_year == 2013)
```

For each of these you'll update `hits` to be true if any other row satisfies some complicated condition; it's not obvious how to avoid the outer loop (although specific features of your data (e.g., only a few IDs) might suggest a different strategy), but the inner loop can be *vectorized* as

```
for (i in i_idx)
    hits[i] <- any(d[, date1] < d[i, lookupdate] &
                   d[, date2] > d[i, lookupdate] &
                   d[, ID] == d[i, ID] &
                   seq_len(nrow(d)) < i)
}
```

So combined and with a little optimization

```
calc_hits_bruteforce <- function(d) {
    hits <- logical(nrow(d))
    i_idx <- which(d$financial_year == 2013)
    for (i in i_idx) {
        lkup <- d[i, lookupdate]
        hits[i] <- any((d$date1 < lkup) & (d$date2 > lkup) &
                       (d$ID == d[i, ID]) & (seq_len(nrow(d)) < i))

    }
    hits
}
```

This will be faster than your original, but does not exploit the sorted nature of your data and will scale approximately with the number of rows in your data frame (instead of with the square of the number of rows, as in your original algorithm).

One possible improvement is to use the Bioconductor [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) package. Install and attach with

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")
library(IRanges)
```

IRanges are integer-valued, so representation of dates becomes important. I read your data as

```
txt <- "ID     lookupdate      date1      date2 financial_year
C143896B 2011-02-24 2011-11-09 2011-11-21           2011
C143896G 2010-11-23 2011-10-29 2011-11-21           2011
C143896G 2011-11-11 2012-10-12 2012-11-05           2012
C143896G 2012-06-17 2013-01-30 2013-02-11           2013
C143896G 2012-10-31 2013-09-15 2013-09-29           2013"

d <- read.delim(textConnection(txt),
                colClasses=c("factor", "Date", "Date", "Date", "integer"),
                sep="")
```

Then represent the dates and lookup as IRanges (the range representation includes end points, but you're not interested in that).

```
dates = with(d, IRanges(as.integer(date1) + 1, as.integer(date2) - 1))
lkup = with(d, IRanges(as.integer(lookupdate), width=1))
```

Find overlapping ranges (this finds all overlapping ranges; we weed out the unwanted values later; the comparison is efficient, as described on the help page ?IntervalTree)

```
olaps = findOverlaps(query=dates, subject=lkup)
```

and fine-tune

```
q_hits = queryHits(olaps); s_hits = subjectHits(olaps)
keep = (d[s_hits, "financial_year"] == 2013) &
    (d[s_hits, "ID"] == d[q_hits, "ID"]) & (q_hits < s_hits)
tabulate(s_hits[keep], length(lkup)) != 0
```

This will be fast, though I might have got the edge cases wrong.

Comment: I'm getting this error running your code: `Warning messages:
1: In seq_len(nrow(d)) < i_idx :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: OK, that works, but it's still pretty slow. I was hoping there's a way to smartly exploit the fact that the dates are ordered, i.e. there's no need to compare all rows, just the few rows above the current one until the ID doesn't match anymore...

Comment: @phildeutsch I updated the answer with use of IRanges from Bioconductor, which should be 'fast'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, looks like a pretty handy package. In this case, it still seems like suck a waste to compare every combination of rows though.

Comment: @phildeutsch findOverlaps does the comparison efficiently; not every combination of rows is compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- structure(list(ID = c("C143896B", "C143896G", "C143896G", "C143896G", 
"C143896G"), lookupdate = structure(c(15029, 14936, 15289, 15508, 
15644), class = "Date"), date1 = structure(c(15287, 15276, 15625, 
15735, 15963), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(15299, 15299, 
15649, 15747, 15977), class = "Date"), financial_year = c(2011, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2013)), .Names = c("ID", "lookupdate", "date1", 
"date2", "financial_year"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would suggest this but I'm afraid I could not test its performance:

```
calc_hits_bruteforce2 <- function(db){
 a <- sapply(test[,2],FUN=function(x)(test[,3] < x & x < test[,4] ))
 b <- sapply(test[,1],FUN=function(x)(x==test[,1]))
 c <- matrix(sapply(test[,5], FUN=function(x)(x==2013)),nrow(a),nrow(a), byrow=T)
 d <- a==TRUE & a==b & a==c
 rows <- round(which(d==TRUE)/nrow(a))
 test[rows,]
}


##         ID lookupdate      date1      date2 financial_year
## 5 C143896G 2012-10-31 2013-09-15 2013-09-29           2013
```